# Expectation value of a Guessing Game

Tags: probability, expected-value

I recently watched a James Randi video where they took five people in order behind a screen and made a "psychic" put them in the correct order when they were called out randomly.

James said by chance alone you would expect to get 1 in the correct spot, where does this number come from? Is it true that the probability of getting n in the correct order is $5Cn/5!$?

Comment: see [this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/) for a proof of linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 2):

Since order matters there are $5!$ different ways of assigning orderings. Name the people 1,2,..,5 and place them in a uniformly random order. Let $X_i$ be 1 if you guess the $i$’th persons order correctly and 0 otherwise. The total number of people correctly guessed is $X_1+\cdots+X_5$, is a random variable. The expectation of guessing any given persons order is $1/5$, so by linearity of expectation you’d expect to guess 1 persons order correctly.